# DotNetOpenAuth Issue with Yahoo!

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, dotnetopenauth

I use OpenID authentication and all of the providers have been tested and work fine when running the website from Visual Studio. I have deployed the website to the server and the Google and myOpenID work just fine but Yahoo! OpenID provider just throws this error...

> The OpenID Provider issued an
>   assertion for an Identifier whose
>   discovery information did not match.
>   Assertion endpoint info:
>   ClaimedIdentifier:
>   https://me.yahoo.com/a/KyzgPcp9v8xRcWxFNKx357hQTxZ9P7Udww8bPkpv3oNSoogH0IXw#11950
>   ProviderLocalIdentifier:
>   https://me.yahoo.com/a/KyzgPcp9v8xRcWxFNKx357hQTxZ9P7Udww8bPkpv3oNSoogH0IXw
>   ProviderEndpoint:
>   https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth
>   OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs:
>   Discovered endpoint info: [{
>   ClaimedIdentifier:
>   http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
>   ProviderLocalIdentifier:
>   http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
>   ProviderEndpoint:
>   https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth
>   OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs:
>   http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server
>   http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0
>   http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
>   http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0
>   http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/lang-pref
>   http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0/mode/popup
>   http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier
>   http://www.idmanagement.gov/schema/2009/05/icam/no-pii.pdf
>   http://www.idmanagement.gov/schema/2009/05/icam/openid-trust-level1.pdf
>   http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-63/SP800-63V1_0_2.pdf
>   },]

If anyone has any idea why this is happening I would really appreciate it. This only occurs on the server so I can't debug it easily.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggests that your RP is performing discovery on the original identifier ("yahoo.com") instead of the claimed identifier in the assertion.  Can you [activate logging](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/loggingdebugging-dotnetopenauth-with-log4net/) and include the entire surrounding log from the server in your question?